# setInterval not working with async funtion in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am just learning to react native and I am trying to record video and show remaining video duration in the screen.

I am using the below code:

```
setInterval (() => {
                    this.setState ({progress: progress * 2});
                  }, 1000);
                  var video = await this.camera.recordAsync ({
                    mute: true,
                    quality: '480p',
                    maxDuration: this.state.max_duration,
                  });
```

However video is recording perfectly fine, but setiInterval has stopped worked. How to run setInterval in a `async funtion` ? Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript/ReactJS/React-Native do not have a native sleep function. Since the implementation of promises and async/await in ES2018, you can do this to perform a setTimeout/setInterval:

**To set a setInterval for an async function:**

```
setInterval(async () => {
    await print("waiting") 
}, 2000);
```

(Also try this) You can make the function recursive. This way you can start a timeout for the next iteration once the function has completed.

```
async function doSomething() {
    //code to run on a interval

    setTimeout(doSomething, 2000); // <------------------
 
}
setTimeout(doSomething, 2000);
```

**To set a setTimeout for an async function, like a sleep function:**

First place this in your code as a function

```
    const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
    }
```

Now use this inside the async function:

```
await sleep(2000)
```

You can also use this as well

```
    sleep(500).then(() => {
      console.log("waiting"); 
      
    })
```